# How to detect hangup event in Freeswitch?

Tags: perl, voip, freeswitch

I'm new to `Freeswitch` and looking for help from experts. My problem is below.

I'm trying to do below scenario in `Perl`:

When I'm getting an incoming call to script (`test.pl`) I play a file to it and then put inbound session to on-hold. Then I try to make new outbound session from a separate script (`test2.pl`). If outbound call get answer, then I `break` inbound session from on-hold and `bridge` both sessions. The scrips are like below.

**test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $session;

if( $session->ready() ) {
    $session->setVariable( 'hangup_after_bridge', 'false' );
    $session->setVariable( 'continue_on_fail', 'true' );
    $session->answer();

    my $api = new freeswitch::API;
    $api->execute('perlrun', '/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts/test2.pl ' . $session->get_uuid());
    $session->setVariable('playback_timeout_sec', '70');
    $session->execute("playback", '$${hold_music}');

    if ($session->getVariable('outbound_answered') == 'true') {
        my $outbound_uuid = $session->getVariable('outbound_uuid');
        my $outbound_session = new freeswitch::Session($outbound_uuid);

        if ($outbound_session->ready()) {
            $session->bridge($outbound_session);
        } else {
            # outbound session disconnected.
        }
    }  else {
        # outbound session didn't answer.
    }
} else {
    # Inbound disconneected.
}
1;
```

**test2.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $api = new freeswitch::API;
my $inbound_uuid = $ARGV[0];
my $inbound_session = new freeswitch::Session( $inbound_uuid );

my $originate_str = "sofia/gateway/outbound/0416661666";
my $outbound_session = new freeswitch::Session( $originate_str );
my $hangup_cause_out = $outbound_session->hangupCause();
$inbound_session->setVariable( 'outbound_uuid', $outbound_session->get_uuid() );

if ( $outbound_session->ready() ) {
    if ( $inbound_session->ready() ) {
        $inbound_session->setVariable('outbound_answered', 'true');
        $outbound_session->streamFile("/usr/share/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/ivr/8000/ivr-please_hold_while_party_contacted.wav");
        $inbound_session->execute('break');
        while ($inbound_session->ready()) {
            sleep(10);
            # Inbound sessnio ok, continue outbound session.
        }
    } else {
        # Inbound session got disconnected while we trying outbound.
    }
} else {
    # Outbound call failed.
}
1;
```

**Debian syslog:**

```
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: freeswitch.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: Stopped freeswitch.
Jul 19 13:14:50 XXX systemd[1]: Starting freeswitch...
```

The expected scenario work without issues. But my issue is Freeswitch getting restart when inbound session hangup by incoming call party while `Freeswitch` ringing outbound party.

UPDATE1:
I think I need to handle inbound session hangup event but kinda lost here. May be I'm doing all wrong.

UPDATE2:
I been seen this issue in Freeswitch 1.8.7. I tried testing the same code in Freeswitch 1.6.20 and it didn't crash, but gave below error,
`[ERR] freeswitch_perl.cpp:114 session is not initalized`
So it seems Freeswitch 1.8 mod_perl module not handling it properly.

Looking for suggestions from `Freeswitch` experts.

Thank you!